# Assigning properties dynamically at runtime

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to setup a debug flash app for a fellow developer to work with the API I'm building. 
It's just a basic swf with a txtfield for a API url, function name, a section to add post params, and a break down of the data he gets back.
It works great when I hard code the "msg" post parameter in the loadVars class.

```
myloadVars.msg=variable1.text
```

The problem is I want to be able to allow him to add his own parameters at runtime via a textbox for the name of the the parameter and a textbox for the data he is sending. I've been trying to figure this out for hours. This is , in my mind, how it should look:

```
var myloadVars:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
for (var i=0; i<params.length(); i++) {
     myloadVars.this["param_txt.text"] = param_text.text;
     i++;
}
myloadVars.sendAndLoad(target, myloadVars, "POST");
```

The main goal here is there is a textfield to contain a var name and a textfield to contain the value of the var to be posted. A button to add it to an array and when it comes time to add the post values to the loadVars class it just iterates through them, adding them name and value intact then sends away to be handled by my back end scripts.

I have been hung up for hours trying to figure out how to take a literal string (value from the textfield that has the POST var name in it) and adding it to the loadVars class.

I just want:

```
var params:Object = new Object();
GUI:
Param: ["course_ID"]   Data: ['222'] [Add param] *click*
param[0]-> array("course_ID", "222");

Param: ["course_name"]   Data: ['Math3'] [Add param] *click*
param[1]-> array("course_name", "Math3");
```

translate to something like:
*some kind of pseudo foreach loop*

```
foreach() {
myloadVars.Param = Data;
}
```

(Sorry about the heavy pseudo code. I'm writing in about 5 languages at the moment and no bother to get the exact syntax right for the example)
But no matter what I try I can not take the string input from the textfield and use it for the property name of the loadVars class.

long story short. I have a textfield that takes a string. I want to use that string to name the property of the loadVar property that will be posting to my backend script. 
Instead of hard coding:

```
myloadVars.class_id = param_data.text;
```

I'd like something like `

```
myloadVars.this["param_name_text"].text = param_data.text;
```

but I can't seem to get that to work...

any help here guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
myloadVars[param_name_text.text] = param_data.text;
```

Assuming that the param_name_text is the reference of your variable name input field and you have entered myVariableName there this will store the param_data.text as myLoadVars.myVariableName

It might be a good idea to check for empty values before sending stuff to the server though